# VBScript "ALTt" or "{ENTER}" don't select the button, it merely highlights it

Tags: vbscript

There is a "Test" button, in an application that I'm looking to automatically select.
I'm using VBScript and have tried "ALTt" (t is the underlined character in the button's text) and "{ENTER}" but it merely highlights the button and doesn't actually select it.

Here's the script:

```
Set WshShell = WScript.CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
Set oShell = CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
WshShell.AppActivate "IMPORT"
WshShell.SendKeys "ALTt"
```

or

```
Set WshShell = WScript.CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
Set oShell = CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
WshShell.AppActivate "IMPORT"
WshShell.SendKeys "{TAB}"
WshShell.SendKeys "{TAB}"
WshShell.SendKeys "{ENTER}"
```

Unfortunately, as mentioned this just highlights the button.
I've also tried the tilde character in place of "{ENTER}" but it yields the same results.

Answer (score 0):

I think Space can also "press" a button once it has focus, you can give that a shot.

As far as sending ALT, take a look at the [Microsoft documentation for SendKeys statement](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/sendkeys-statement), you should be sending `%t` according to that.

Comment: Unfortunately, the %t doesn't work but ALTt did, up until last Friday, now that doesn't even work.  Not even {TAB} works anymore.  Space doesn't even work either.